# How to wait all Promises to resolve in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

### Background:

I have a simple REST API in ExpressJS that allows phasing multiple pages together. The page numbers are dynamic.

### Issue:

Because of performance constraints, I would like to implement async promises when fetching multiple web pages, wait for all of them finished download, phrase them with my desired format, and return back to the output.

After I researched all the stuff about promises and async online (since I'm still new to this async topic), Most of them told me to use `Promise.all`, **but I just can't get it to work somehow.**

### Current output when navigating to `GET /xxx`

```
{
    username: xxx
    parsedHTML: []
}
```

### Targeted output:

```
{
    username: xxx
    parsedHTML: [
        "BUNCH OF ANALYSED HTML",
        "BUNCH OF ANALYSED HTML",
        "BUNCH OF ANALYSED HTML",
        ...
    ]
}
```

### Code

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = express();

app.get("/:username", (req, res)=>{
    const username = req.params.username;
    let page = 3; //Will be obtained dynamically. But for now, I'll put a constant here
    res.json({
        username: username,
        parsedHTML: getParsedHTML(username, page),
    });
    console.log("Page sent")
})

function getParsedHTML(username, page) {

    let promises = [];
    let analyses = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < (page + 1); i++) {
        promises.push(fetch(`https://example.com/profile/${username}/?page=${i}`)
                .then((c) => c.text()));
        // console.log(`Added promise`)
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
        for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
            let promise = promises[i];
           analyses.push(analyse(promise));

        }
    })
    return analyses;
}

function analyse(html){
    // Some synchronous analyse stuff here
    // Right now it do nothing
    return html;
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('API listening on port ' + 3000 + '!'))
```

---

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Promise.all` on the `promises` correctly, but the `getParsedHTML` function *isn't waiting* for that `Promise.all` call to resolve before returning. So, your `res.json` is running *immediately, synchronously*, and the `analyses` that are returned is an empty array.

Return the `Promise.all` call instead, and make sure to `analyze` the *responses* (from the `Promise.all` call) rather than the Promises:

```
return Promise.all(promises).then((responses)=>{
  for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    let response = responses[i];
    analyses.push(analyse(response));
  }
}).then(() => analyses);
```

But you can significantly clean up your code by mapping the resulting array of responses:

```
function getParsedHTML(username, page) {
  let promises = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < (page + 1); i++) {
    promises.push(fetch(`https://example.com/profile/${username}/?page=${i}`)
                  .then((c) => c.text()));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then((responses) => responses.map(analyse));
}
```

Also make sure for to wait for `getParsedHTML` to wait for the returned Promises to resolve before sending `res.json`:

```
app.get("/:username", (req, res)=>{
  const username = req.params.username;
  let page = 3; //Will be obtained dynamically. But for now, I'll put a constant here
  getParsedHTML(username, page)
    .then((parsedHTML) => {
      res.json({
        username,
        parsedHTML
      });
      console.log("Page sent")
    });
})
```

Comment: Your first code block is calling `analyse(promise)`.  That sure doesn't look right.  You want to be dealing with resolved results after `Promise.all()` not still with the promises.  If you do deal with the promises, you have to use `.then()` on them to get the result out.  Probably need `Promise.all(promises).then(results => { /* use results array here */})`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This problem has been stuck on me for few hours :(

Comment: you can clean up the code even more by chaining the `analyse` in the main loop - or even go a one liner `return Promise.all(Array.from({length:page},(_, i)=>i+1).map(i => fetch(`https://example.com/profile/${username}/?page=${i}`).then((c) => c.text()).then(analysise));` - that's clean :p